# Showing whether a list in Excel has a 1 or a 0 in it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a column in excel that I want to roll up into one row. Essentially the column has a `0` if a feature isn't present, and a `1` if it is.

What I want to do is get excel to check a column, lets say `B2:B30`, and, if there is a `1` in any of those rows to show a `1` in `B1`. If there is a `0` in all the rows, then I need it to show a `0`.

Looked at lots of stuff online, and I can get it to count the number of rows with a certain number (or just use a pivot table), but I can't get it to roll up and just show a simple `0` or `1`.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to wrap whatever formula you're using now in an `IF` statement that returns `1` for the condition being met and `0` for not.

For example:

```
=IF(SUM(B2:B30)>0,1,0)
```

Answer (score 5):

If the column's cells always contain either `0` or `1` as values (and what you want as a result is 1 when there's at least a 1 in any of the cells and 0 otherwise) then a simple `=MAX(B2:B30)` is enough.

Comment: Yeah... so simple so clear, why make things complex when there's no need? I think this one should definitively be the accepted answer +1!

Comment: @danicotra: Thanks, just arithmetic `MAX` is a known replacement for logical `OR`, it is essentially the same as `=OR(B2:B30)*1`.

Comment: You actually have only 2 answers on superuser but I simply remained jaw-dropped astonished and amazed by your overturning approach to problems/solutions. In [your other answer](http://superuser.com/questions/931682/excel-remove-leading-0s-from-ip-address/931726) you broke the "classical scheme" compared to others finding a blazing (and uncommon) solution. In this one you got straight to the point quickly noticing there was a trivial solution. I think you must be some kind of genius, if this were Twitter you'd have me among your brand new followers! :D

Answer (score 1):

I suppose:

```
    =IF(COUNTIF(B2:B30)=0,0,1)
```

would work too, but maybe Excellll's one is marginally faster.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'roll up' you mean group all of the 0 in one area, and all the 1 in another then sort the table by 0 and 1 (i.e. sort by column b), then use the '[Group](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-HA010095247.aspx)' function